# Emailjs - emailjs-mime-parser Example

Tags: javascript, email, mime

I'm trying to read MIME text with http://emailjs.org/ but I get the javascript error 'MimeParser is not defined'

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/emailjs/emailjs-mime-codec.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/emailjs/emailjs-addressparser.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/emailjs/emailjs-mime-parser.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var p = new MimeParser();
        });    

    </script>
```

The JavaScript files are loading properly.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var parser = new this['emailjs-mime-parser'];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing one java script `emailjs-stringencoding.js`
2. Try to include in below order

   ```
   emailjs-addressparser.js

   emailjs-stringencoding.js

   emailjs-mime-codec.js

   emailjs-mime-parser.js

   jquery.min.js
   ```
3. You can create an object using below syntax

   ```
   var parser = new this['emailjs-mime-parser'];
   ```